# Push Notifications on conditions

Tags: task-notifications

I am working on salesforce mobile app.

I enabled push notifications in the sandbox and I can see the bell icon on standard account detail page.

Now the issue is i want to show notifications on account detail page whenever the child records in related list meets a criteria.

There is picklist on child records of account object, whenever the child records picklist is 'New', there should be a notification on account list view page which is a vf page.

When i open and click notifications, it should take the user to that specific child record.

Can some please give me inputs in how to start this.